# Settings to rotate display by 90 degrees

Tags: windows-xp, display, rotate

A friend (I know how that sounds) has managed to rotate her desktop display by 90 degrees.

Right now she has had to physically rotate her monitor so that everything looks fine.

She says she does not know how she did it and that she just "pressed a whole lot of buttons on the keyboard".

How does one fix this?

Comment: Is the password on the post-it?

Comment: @echo lol, but unfortunately I had to remove the image. I can't access any image hosting sites that can give me a perma-link to an image. The internet rules here at the office are a little 'Gestapo'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Control-Alt-(Arrow key)

Only works on some video cards.

Comment: Accepted this one. cause it worked (but might not for other cards) and was first.

Comment: If you dig into the advanced settings for the video card. You can usually turn this feature off so it doesn't happen again. For ATI cards this would be in the Catalyst Control Center.

Answer (score 3):

I think she has ATI graphic card.

try one of these shortcuts

- right 90° - Ctrl+Alt+Right
- left 90° - Ctrl+Alt+Left
- standard - Ctrl+Alt+Up

Comment: Upside-down - Ctrl-Alt-Down. (Some PCs at my school have ATIs.)

Answer (score 2):

Try right click the desktop and after that, see if you have "Graphics Options". This can be dependent of the software that came with the graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

If your friend has an Nvidia card, the settings can be found in the Nvidia Control Panel, under "Rotation" in the left column.  You may need to go into an advanced mode to get access to this option.

Answer (score 0):

With an ATI card, the Ctrl-Alt options don't work. Use the ATI "Catalyst Control Center", under Displays Manager: Rotation.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the Desktop Screen or Flip it use Keyboard and Press Ctrl + Alt + Uparrow for 90 degree default or other cursor keys like Down Arrow, Left or Right in Windows XP.  This does not work in Windows 7.

Answer (score -2):

I am afraid you have to turn it off at the plug and turn back on as this resets the screen settings hope this helps

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.